# iOS process audio stream while playing video

Tags: ios, audio, video, real-time, avfoundation

I am trying to create a video player for iOS, but with some additional audio track reading. I have been checking out MPVideoPlayerController, and also AVPlayer in the AV Foundation, but it's all kinda vague.
What I am trying to do is play a video (from a local .mp4), and while the movie is playing **get the current audio buffer/frames**, so I can do some calculations and other (not video/audio relevant) actions that depend on the currently played audio. This means that the video should keep on playing, with its audio tracks, but I also want the live raw audio data for calculations (like i.e.: getting the amplitude for certain frequency's).

Does anyone have an example or hints to do this ? Of-course I checked out Apple's AV Foundation library documentation, but it was not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a really (really) long time Googling, I found a blog post that describes **MTAudioProcessingTap**. Introduced in iOS 6.0, it solves my problem perfectly.

The how-to/blogpost can be found here : http://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/

I Hope it helps anyone else now....... The only thing popping up for me Googling (with a lot of different terms) is my own post here. And as long as you don't know MTAudioProcessingTap exists, you don't know how to Google for it :-)

Comment: Hi, Niek, a follow up question, does MTAudioProcessingTap support multichannel  (>2) ? Thx in advance!

Comment: @PeiXiang yes, check the link in this answer. bufferListInOut->mBuffers contains a collection of the different channels, see the piece of code on the bottom of the blog post.

Comment: Thanks @Niek, Yes, bufferListInOut is a list that can contain multiple buffers, however if we stuff more than two channel into MTAudioProcessingTap, the system will work funky and MTAudioProcessingTap's "prepare" callback never get invoked. Given that it has "left" and "right" concept inside its struct, I doubt if more than 2 channel cases are not supported ...